# I'm trying to make an ArrayList public(in java) so I can access it in a different class, what am I doing wrong?

Tags: java, arraylist

There is an error and I'm not sure what I'm supposed to do without being unable to access the ArrayList in another class

```
package LifeGame;
import java.util.ArrayList;
public class Lists {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
    public ArrayList<String> tasks = new ArrayList<String>(); { // error on `tasks`
        tasks.add("Phone");
    }

    }
}
```

Comment: `public` (or any access) modifier cannot be used in a method. Declare the array list outside the method.

Comment: Post code, not images of code. You need a class member not a method variable.

Comment: Variables inside a method can not have access modifier.

Comment: Additionally, the block (the `{}` around the `add`) here isn't doing anything useful. It looks like you've attempted to use double brace initialization; you haven't, but *don't*.

Answer (score 2):

Variables inside a method are only accessible by name from inside that same method. Class members — variable defined outside of methods — are the only ones that can be public, private, etc.

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to declare it outside the method  as a class member

```
package LifeGame;
import java.util.ArrayList;
public class Lists
{
   public static ArrayList<String> tasks;

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        tasks =  new ArrayList<String>();
        tasks.add("Phone");
   }
}
```

So you can use this anywhere. Eg:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Lists {
    public static ArrayList<String> tasks;

    public Lists() {
        tasks = new ArrayList<String>();
    }
    public void addTask(String task) {
        tasks.add(task);
    }
    public ArrayList<String> getTasks(){
        return tasks;
    }
    public void printTasks() {
        System.out.println(tasks);
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Lists l = new Lists();

        l.addTask("Phone");
        l.addTask("Clean");
        l.printTasks();

    }

}
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score -1):

Your code should be:

```
package LifeGame;
import java.util.ArrayList;
public class Lists {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
     ArrayList<String> tasks = new ArrayList<String>(); 
     tasks.add("Phone");    
  }
}
```