# how to access arraylist of another class

Tags: java, class, arraylist

Suppose I have a class manager which stores Arraylist of class Employee say:

```
class Manager {

    ArrayList<Employee> x = new ArrayList<>();
}
```

Now is it possible to get the name of Manager object by some method in Employee class? In other words, finding the name of Arraylist using element.

Comment: What do you mean by the name of `ArrayList`? do you need the variable name `x`?

Comment: x is just an example name of Arraylist that stores Employee objects.

Comment: Can elaborate more, what exactly you need?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [I'm trying to make an ArrayList public(in java) so I can access it in a different class, what am I doing wrong?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51803592/im-trying-to-make-an-arraylist-publicin-java-so-i-can-access-it-in-a-differen)

Comment: Okay, i have two classes Employee and Manager, not inherited . Now Manager class stores Employee class instances in an  ArrayList variable. I can obviously know the elements (ie Employee objects) stored in Manager.Arraylist , but how to do reverse of it. Knowing the name of Manager class object through Employee .

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get the manager object from employee object then you have to implement bi directional mapping.
Add manager attribute in employee class as well.

Answer (score 0):

The problem as I understand, is to find the manager of a given employee. To do this you'll need a list of all managers and the details of the employee you search the manager for.

```
class Manager
    {
       private String name;
       private List<Employee> employees;

       public List<Employee> getEmployees()
       {
         return this.employees;
       }

       public String getName()
       {
          return this.name;
       }
    }
```

If you are using existing object of an Employee (You get the Employee object out of a list of employees in a Manager object), following approach will work.

```
class FunctionClass{
   public static void main(String[] args)
   {
      List<Manager> allManagers = getAllManagers();
      Employee currEmployee = getCurrentEmployee();

      for( Manager manager : allManagers )
      {
         if( manager.getEmployees().contains( currEmployee ) )
         {
            System.out.println( manager.getName() );
            break;
         }
      }
   }
}
```

If you are creating objects of Employee from provided data, above approach will not work. You will have to iterate through all the employees of each manager.

```
class FunctionClass{
       public static void main(String[] args)
       {
          List<Manager> allManagers = getAllManagers();
          Employee currEmployee = getCurrentEmployee();

          for( Manager manager : allManagers )
          {
             for( Employee emp: manager.getEmployees() )
             {
                if( /*compare if emp and currEmployee equal*/ )
                {
                  System.out.println( manager.getName() );
                  break;
                }
          }
       }
    }
```